# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn t boot after automatic upgrades were installed

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, updates

I have been using ubuntu for a month and until now there were no problems. After I ran the automatic updates last night,today ubuntu can no longer boot, even with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I can't boot to run commands.

Tried everything from recovery console, I entered command shell from recovery console (I think that is the right term) to try and add these commands I found on the ubuntu help forums regarding nvidia drivers:`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304` and `sudo apt-get nvidia current`, but it doesn't recognize these commands. So basically after starting computer all I see is a line that keeps blinking and nothing works.

Comment: what is the output of `startx` command

Answer (score 0):

I think the ploblem is about the new kernel 3.8.0-34 with the proprietary driver of nvidia. I solved with a new istallation of ubuntu 12.04 without update the kernel and istall only driver raccomanded by jokey (319.xx ). I don't know if there is a solution less complicated. with rescue mode I try but I don't solved.